# Rails ActiveRecord How to add additional field to params.fetch( modelName )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

When I post addition field to post action such as { "xx": 7 ... }

`{"user_email"=>"scott@student", "user_pw"=>"123456", "xx"=>7, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create", "user"=>{"user_pw"=>"123456", "user_email"=>"scott@student"}}`

I can not found the "xx=>7" in "user" attribute. How can I move it to param["user"]["xx"].

## Here is my code

due to "xx" is not UserModel attributes so, I guess that UserController using fields of UserModel to filter all parameters automatically, if the controllerName is mapped with modelName with same naming rule. So finnally I missing "xx" in user node inside.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # include fields: uid, user_name, user_mobile.
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user).extract!(:uid).permit!
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    user.save!
    render :nothing => true, :status => 202
  end
end
```

I can set a trick wrap_parameter setting in controller

```
wrap_parameters :user, include: User.column_names << 'xx'
```

or

```
wrap_parameters true
# but user node will be "true" => {"xxx": "test", "user_name": ... }, acception all field even if it's not UserModel attributes.
```

Finally, I want that the wrap_parameters 'user' without setup include all columns which client send to server. I don't want to setup like include: [*column_names].

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are currently relying on [parameter wrapping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html), in particular you're letting it work in its most automatic mode. In this scenario if there is a param named foo submitted to `UsersController` and if the model `User` has a field of that name then rails copies it into `params[:user]`.

You can change this behaviour in two ways: you could redefine `attribute_names` on your model to return this extra column. I'm not sure what else uses that method though - may have unintended consequences elsewhere.

The less disruptive change would be to put

```
wrap_parameters User, include: [:user_pw, :user_email, :xx]
```

At the top of the controller, to explicitly tell action controller which params should be treated in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your `form` partial/view you have to put the hidden attribute or however you set the `xx` value inside the form.

```
<%= form_for @user, do |f| %>
  ......
  <%= f.hidden_field :xx, value: "7" %>
<% end %>
```

This way it will be under `"user"`.

Comment: I found that If the property of json request body is one of the model field, it will be move to user node automatically.

I want add a one field and make it move inside user node but I dont want format like { "user" : { "xx": "123" } }

Comment: @scott1028 Can you share your form and controller code? It should not be the case since you could have params like `"id" => 1, "user" => {"id"=> 2}` where one `id` represents `user` record, but the other one completely something else and it would create a conflict.